# Randomly increment a key in a python dictionary until all of the keys have the same value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, random

I have 5 groups - A,B,C,D,E. I want to pick a random letter within the group letters, but I need exactly 4 instances of each letter

So in the end I want four As, four Bs, four Cs four Ds, and four Es, but I want to pick them randomly.

Using a dictionary was the best way I thought I could do this. I can keep track of how many letters I have this way, but I'm not certain how to write out code such that each letter only appears four times.

```
import random
random.seed(1)

groups = {
          'A' : 0,
          'B' : 0,
          'C' : 0,
          'D' : 0,
          'E' : 0,
          }

#return a random letter between A and E, the keys of the group dictionary
def random_letter():
    return random.choice(list(groups.keys()))    

while (groups['A'] != 4) and (groups['B'] != 4): #What can I put here so that it makes all of the groups A to E have only 4. using 'and' here isnt working im assuming because im using it incorrectly
    groups[random_letter()] += 1 
    
print(list(groups.keys())) #should return ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
print(list(groups.values())) #should return [4,4,4,4,4]
```

Comment: Why not just make a list containing each letter 4 times and then shuffle the list? (okay, I get this scales badly if "4" is actually a large number)

Comment: why do you want to do this? why not just build a dict where each value is 4?

Comment: Why do you want to pick them randomly if the outcome is always the same?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the simplest way I could do it.

```
str_options = "abcde" * 4
options_as_list = list(str_options)
random.shuffle(options_as_list)
print(options_as_list)
```

Comment: You don't need to make a list,. a string is a sequence already.

Comment: I tried, but shuffle didn't allow it. TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Ah you're right it shuffles in place and strings are immutable. Another reason to use `sample` then! 

Comment: sample is good but it requires you to keep count of amount of samples necessary, so if you change the number of options or the number of repetitions you also have to add it to the value of n_samples. for the specific case where you want all options, i think shuffle is good enough then. Sample indeed has more flexibility though.

Comment: Sure although I dislike casting anything to a  list in Python. I take it as a sign something can be improved.

Comment: I mean, it could easily be ['a', 'b'...] * 4 to jump the step of casting. Just takes more time to write, and it's a negligible operation for the current example. Given the scope of the question, I focused on readability and not performance.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random

res = random.sample('ABCDE', counts=[4]*5, k=20)
```

If all the letters always have the same number of occurrences:

```
res = random.sample('ABCDE'*4, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the desired choices into a list and shuffle it only once:

```py
import random
random.seed(1)

groups = {
    'A': 0,
    'B': 0,
    'C': 0,
    'D': 0,
    'E': 0
}

full_list = [*groups]*4
random.shuffle(full_list)
print(full_list)
```

Comment: kudos to Arson, I didn't see when I was writing it, but this is more complete and more flexible as it picks up `groups` instead of using hard-coded values. Do you think mine should be removed?

Comment: No, I think it is fine. I missing that `groups` was a thing the OP defined :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice


groups = dict.fromkeys("ABCDE", 0)

while (key_pool := [key for key in groups if groups[key] != 4]):
    key = choice(key_pool)
    print(f"Incrementing {key}")
    groups[key] += 1
```

Explanation: `dict.fromkeys("ABCDE", 0)` is a convenient short-hand for creating a dictionary, in this case, with the keys `A` through `E`, all mapping to the value `0`.

`while (key_pool := [key for key in groups if groups[key] != 4]):` is pretty dense. We keep iterating as long as there exist keys which do not map to a count of `4`. We generate that list of keys with the list comprehension, which we assign to `key_pool` via the so-called "walrus operator".

`key = choice(key_pool)` picks a random key from the collection of possible keys (keys that don't map to `4`.)

`groups[key] += 1` increments the value of the chosen key.

---

That being said, it's not immediately obvious from your question what you actually intend to do with this dictionary. Re-reading your question makes me wonder if what you really want is just a string with the letters `A` through `E`, each appearing four times in some random order?

If that's the case, maybe something like this?:

```
from random import sample

chars = "ABCDE"

print("".join(sample(chars*4, k=len(chars)*4)))
```

`chars*4` will yield the string `'ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE'`
`random.sample` will pick `k` characters from that string (when an element is picked, that element will not be considered in successive samples).
`"".join(...)` joins a collections of strings into a single string.